# How to create unit tests for a new MVC framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phpunit

I have been learning MVC recently and have started creating my own framework (for learning purposes only, of course) from http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

I want to be able to extend these base classes but first I would like to be able to unit test them. Does anyone have an idea how I would go about testing the base Controller, Model and Template classes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Create a test file for each file 2) Write the tests 3) Run the tests >:)

Comment: Thanks, but what should I be testing for? I'm sorry if I was too vague.

Comment: Many MVC frameworks come with their own unit testing tools. You might want to study them and see how they solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write test classes, preferably mirroring your framework structure (eg `ControllerTest`, `ModelTest`, etc), that put the classes through their paces, meaning putting in some data and checking the output. If your code is well-structured, should be quite easy to implement.

**Edit**

Basically, what you test in a unit test is `if ( Class::methodToTest( $input ) === $expected_output )`. The output must **always** be identical for the same `$input`. If this is not the case, or you can't test write a test case like this, it's often an indicator that your code is not well structured (object oriented and loosely coupled).

Your `Template::render()` method for example, is not testable because it prints the data instead of returning it. Now, you could work around this by using `ob_start()`, but better anyway would be to chop the function into smaller parts, that return values instead of directly printing them.

It's a bit abstract, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: If you follow my link you will see all the code :) The classes specifically I want to test are the ontroller, Model and Template classes. Thanks.